# Coupons plugin issue in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, coupon

This is my site.

http://www.vouchersaving.co.uk/store/straight-talk-promo-code/

When I click on Get Deal Button, for any coupon it opens in a new tab with a new link which I want.
When I click on Get Deal Button, it opens in a new tab with same link and opens lightbox coupons code. I placed that over here but it look like same website.

Please help to check this.

http://www.sumocoupon.com/view/kmart.com/

Answer (score 0):

you have to use fancybox for loading content in popup and call that fancybox on load event.

you need to call same url with passing your coupon code like

```
http://www.vouchersaving.co.uk/store/straight-talk-promo-code/?code=12345
```

you call fancybox onload of page if **code** found in url

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery.fancybox();
});
```

Comment: Please tell me, how can I used fancybox loading content in popup and call them into load event??

Comment: As you have not provided code or plugin name, We can't help you much.But As described above, you can pass the unique promo code in the URL and from that you can create custom template if you want in new tab and if you want in same tab you can do as described above